# Typescript: best way to iterate through an object and modify properties values

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript class which contains this method :

```
 updatePropertiesValues()
{
    for (let key in this) {
        if (typeof this[key] == "string") {
            this[key] = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to replace all the values of the properties of type `string`. It works, but the compiler complains : `Type '"test"' is not assignable to type 'this[Extract<keyof this, string>]'.`
Of course, I have many properties in this object, so I don't want to do it one by one.

How can I do this without getting the compiler complaining?

Comment: Have you tried iterating by combining `Object.entries` followed with a `Array.forEach`?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic indeed this seems cleaner. By doing so I'm able to get the values but not modify them. `Object.entries(this).forEach(elmt => elmt[1] = "test");` does not work, and I don't understand why

Comment: Just add `as unknown as (this[typeof key])` to the assignment line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest thing for you to do is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  This is you telling the compiler not to worry about verifying type safety, and that you have checked it yourself and are *asserting* that it's safe:

```
for (let key in this) {
  if (typeof this[key] == "string") {
    this[key] = "test" as any; // assertion
    this[key] = "test" as any as this[typeof key]; // or this one
  }
}
```

Please note that such an assertion represents a shift in the responsibility for verifying type safety from the compiler to you.  You could easily lie to the compiler with a type assertion, and then run into trouble at runtime without any warning from the credulous compiler:

```
    this[key] = 123 as any as this[typeof key]; //  evil liar
```

So be careful.

---

Trying to get the compiler to verify any sort of type safety here without an assertion is a difficult task and probably not worth it. If you're interested I could go through this in detail, but the sketch is:

- The [`this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) is similar to a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type parameter, and therefore it does not get narrowed via control flow analysis (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)) the way a non-generic type would.
- A `for..in` loop or `Object.keys()` does not narrow the keys to be the known keys of the iterated object, because objects might have more properties than the compiler knows about (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208)).
- Unless you know the exact literal key for `key`, an indexed property set like `this[key] = ...` ends up treating the type of the property as an *intersection* of all possible property types (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769)).  This is safer but prevents a lot of ordinary code like `this[key] = this[key]`.

All of this works against you and the easiest thing to do is just assert and move on.  You can try to refactor your code into things the compiler sees as safe, but it's arguably more confusing than just a type assertion.

---

When you say you don't want to do each property one by one, you might try a middle-of-the-road option where you mention the property names twice but only do the setting once:

```
// enumerate keys whose properties can be strings and set them
(["a", "d"] as const).forEach(k => this[k] = "test");
```

If that compiles without error it's because the compiler knows that the `a` and `d` properties of your class are strings.  It's not perfect but it *is* more type safe.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQGcCmcDKcBOCUA5gAr5IAOAPACoA0qA0qpgB5yZQAm6qA1pgCeSMKloA+ABRIARgCsAXOMaChypowBuAQwA2y9ASLEAlKgDeoVKhgojqALbLSO-In3UASpjv5u1JoYxiQSEqgAvKhScEKUmKKocvIA2moAupERUQBERoQkOeYA-EkKqMoWAL4A3NZOacKZUbp6dSBVoKAwejrofABiSEiW9TqRqDk57TayEwCMM7YTBBCYS9wTU0uYC0tiUavr9RCU3Dqc5FSY7giY6ABq+mvoUuZWIDY2YEj40XrYATCVBEVBwAAWCHQ73qXxBYhicQSYghUMaQmauXyJiKo0+cK+qPQ6OaqHmACYAMyoPo0qBCGl8IkpWLxRIZGqoAD0XNQgF4NwAQe6wtAg9Kg9Ag3LCCcyMltOEYcoy6QzaczWcigRjOTzGVhbigCV9pXCsLgQmQKJQYpD0KphIwcgq4EUlnDOvibB7pbquBBHDcLrs1HwAO7gpBYVCUK03RD3Ww6NCyXbYkh8JObM1g8GYRzSqQpHI6HKO7g5TK0uxQIymAB0P3wAFEdDBwVJ+JFwrLSU77i7TEsuviPd6QMPh0A)

Comment: Wow, this is just a perfect answer & solution! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try as follow

```
interface LooseObject {
    [key: string]: any
}

class A {

      prop1: string
      prop2: number
      prop3 = "1";

      constructor() {
            this.prop1 = "";
            this.prop2 = -1;
      }

      updatePropertiesValues() {
            for (var key in this) {
                  if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (typeof this[key] == "string") {
                              const target = this as LooseObject;
                              target[key] = "test";
                        }
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=16&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHt0GcIHkBGAVhAmMgN4BQyNyA2gNYQCeAXMlmFKAOYC67OCGaUAvpUoIANnCxZkAQQoTatAA5R0agIztO3ED2qrkGrQCZ2IAK4BbfNGOqzagMzIAvMgBE27wG4VEwR0EH1rUnQoAAoASmUTROQwAAtgLAA6F21PHwCnJJpU9KzNNXNcgFptQMTxApprNQATOEgABTLoMGAILAA1OClrPriEwtoYKORogDc4KGQmZmRQZLSseKoJieAYGeLMlNlcAHcQTq1u5mjl2K2Gnd396LBmNQh0fcPGFj5PLzefS8bwPJ7gpIhMJkMALHgQMheQ7IWRoTA4AjEUi1CG4opwhG-Zj-QGQTj5PETcSUmjUp501TiepQzgo3IgCCnRRxQJwDJNVodLpQHp9QbDUaxQIs9BSCAZKToHjROBSoA)